# Dynamic property values instead of function?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, dynamic, properties

Is it possible to give an object a *dynamic* **property**, or rather give an object property a *dynamic* **value**? For example:

```
var obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 5,
    c: //should always be a+b
}
```

Obviously I could use a **method** `c=function(){return a+b}`, but then I would always need to call `c` as a **method** using braces (`obj.c()` instead of `obj.c`). This wouldn't really be a problem, but I belive it has to work somehow, since the build in `length` property also is a **property** and not a **function**. This property changes **dynamically** with the object and isn't a function...

```
var str = "hello world";
console.log(str.length); //11
str = "hello stack overflow";
console.log(str.length); //20
```

The property value changes without it beeing updated...

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: You're looking for ES5 getters.  But `.length` is not dynamic; strings are immutable.

Comment: As @SLaks mentions, it is important to note that `String#length` is not a dynamic property because a string's internal value cannot be changed.

Comment: Your string example doesn't prove your point. You are creating a second new string with a different length. The equivalent with your object would be: `var obj = {c: 21}; console.log(obj.c); obj = {c: 42}; console.log(obj.c);`. See, `c` also changed "dynamically" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) when creating the object, or add it later using [`Object#defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Custom_Setters_and_Getters):

```js
var obj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 5,
  get c() { // assign it at object creation
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
};

console.log(obj.c);

// add it to existing object
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'd', {
  get: function() {
    return this.a + this.b + this.c;
  }
});


console.log(obj.d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside getters, you could use an ES6 feature, [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

> The `Proxy` object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

```js
var obj = {
        a: 0,
        b: 5,
    },
    p = new Proxy(obj, {
        get: function(target, prop) {
            return prop === 'c' ? target.a + target.b : target[prop];
        }
    });
   
console.log(p.c); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```
var o = {
   a : 0; 
   b : 1;
   get c () {return this.a + this.b;}

}
```